# Can two families of distributions be conjugate priors for one another?

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

Is it possible to find two families of distributions $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ such that:

- $\mathcal F$ is a conjugate prior for $\mathcal G$
- $\mathcal G$ is a conjugate prior for $\mathcal F$
- $\mathcal F\neq\mathcal G$?

I am mostly interested in cases where $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ can be described by a finite-dimension parameter, but still happy to hear about other cases.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? It's unclear what the conditions are. I'm interpreting this so far as, given a joint model $f(x,\theta)$ and two families $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$, can we have $f(\theta), f(\theta \mid x) \in \mathcal G$ and $f(x), f(x \mid \theta) \in \mathcal F$; in this case, you can get an uninteresting example where $\mathcal X$ and $\Theta$ are finite sets and $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are nonparametric models. You may also get uninteresting examples where $\mathcal F \ne \mathcal G$ because we pulled some reparameterization.

Comment: With your notation, I am looking for: $f(\theta)\in\mathcal G\implies\forall x, f(\theta|x)\in\mathcal G$, and symmetrically for $x|\theta$. Regarding your last sentence, I would argue that if you reparameterize, the family remains the same.

Comment: Isn't there an additional parameter in the conjugate prior when compared with the sampling distribution?

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, of course you are right. My problem is ill-posed. Thanks!